# Object properties is undefined even with value after copy the object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object

i got a object that have 2 of the properties returning undefined even with a value inside of them, when i access them directly like "modelForm.action" it gives the right value but if a just do console.log(modelForm) returns the name undefined

```
 this.modelForm = Object.assign({}, this.formSelected)
 console.log(this.modelForm)
 console.log(this.modelForm.action)
```

//First Log

`action: undefined ​​ company_id: 1 ​​ created_at: "2022-12-19 19:13:21" ​​ deleted_at: null ​​ description: "ewef" ​​ html: null ​​ id: 7 ​​ name: "Form 3" ​​ status: undefined ​​ updated_at: "2022-12-19 19:45:34"`

//Second Log

`default`

Comment: what is the type of formSelected.action ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis string, the active is from status, i got the wrong log, but the active is string too

Comment: could you share a console.log(this.formSelected) before Object.assign ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis  action: "default"
​​
company_id: 1
​​
created_at: "2022-12-19 19:13:21"
​​
deleted_at: null
​​
description: "ewef"
​​
html: null
​​
id: 7
​​
name: "Form 3"
​​
status: "active"
​​
updated_at: "2022-12-20 16:14:51"

Comment: Can you please mention in the question what is the output of `this.formSelected` and please type in a valid JSON format?